# PHP break string into two parts

Tags: php, string, pdf, fpdf

Note: I can't use break or next line functions as i am using FPDF

I am having a problem with php strings. I am having a string where i want to show atmost 12 characters in first row and remaining in second row. So basically i want to break string into two parts and assign to two variables so that i can print those two variables. I have tried following code :-

```
if($length > 12)
       {
         $first400 = substr($info['business_name'], 0, 12);
         $theRest = substr($info['business_name'], 11);
         $this->Cell(140,22,strtoupper($first400));
         $this->Ln();
         $this->Cell(140,22,strtoupper($theRest));
         $this->Ln();
       }
```

But using this I am getting  as shown below :

```
Original String : The Best Hotel Ever
Output : 
The Best Hot
Tel Ever
```

It is breaking a word, i don't want to break the word, just check the length and if within 12 characters all the words are complete then print next word in next line. Like this :

```
Desired OutPut:
The Best 
Hotel Ever
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no built-in function to do it, however you could explode on spaces, and re-build your string until the length with the next words get over 12, everything else going to the second part :

```
$string = 'The Best Hotel Ever';

$exp = explode(' ', $string);

if (strlen($exp[0]) < 12) {
  $tmp = $exp[0];
  $i = 1;
  while (strlen($tmp . ' ' . $exp[$i]) < 12) {
    $tmp .= " " . $exp[$i];
    $i++;
  }
  $array[0] = $tmp;
  while (isset($exp[$i])) {
    $array[1] .= ' ' . $exp[$i];
    $i++;
  }
  $array[1] = trim($array[1]);
} else {
  $array[0] = '';
  $array[1] = trim(implode (' ', $exp));
}

var_dump($array);

// Output : array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "The Best" [1]=> string(10) "Hotel Ever" }

// $string1 = 'The';
// array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "The" [1]=> string(0) "" } 

// $string2 = 'Thebesthotelever';
// array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(16) "Thebesthotelever" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not too crash hot on PHP but it seems to be a simple case of which element of the string you are accessing is futher across from where you want to be:

Try:

```
if($length > 12)
       {
         $first400 = substr($info['business_name'], 0, 8); 
         $theRest = substr($info['business_name'], 11);
         $this->Cell(140,22,strtoupper($first400));
         $this->Ln();
         $this->Cell(140,22,strtoupper($theRest));
         $this->Ln();
    }
```

For further help check out because you need to remember to count from zero up:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Well Clement mallet has a better answer, but if anything i hope i helped

Comment: Clement mallet's Solution worked for me, is a flexible solutions. But thanks for your help too. Paiah